# Merging nested dictionary comparing nested values

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I am trying to merge two nested dictionaries that will merge different dictionaries by comparing values, If the key will be same it will be replaced with the recent value.

Im using always_merger.merge() for merging but is appending the different element.It supposed to compare and replace values with recent one.

```
dictionary_1 = dict([('modifyParameterReq', {
  'managedObject': {
    'distName': 'ethLink_1',
    'operation': 'create_mo',
    'parameter': [

    {
      'parameterName': 'houseName',
      'newValue': 'Bhawan',
      'prevValue': ''
    },
    {
      'parameterName': 'subscribe',
      'newValue': 'TRUE',
      'prevValue': ''
    },

    {
      'parameterName': 'remoteMacAddress',
      'newValue': 'd6-68-05-5e-06-b9',
      'prevValue': ''
    }

    ],
    'class': 'EthernetLink'
  }
})]
)

dictionary_2 = dict([('modifyParameterReq', {
  'managedObject': {
    'distName': 'ethLink_1',
    'operation': 'create_mo',
    'parameter': [

    {
      'parameterName': 'subscribe',
      'newValue': 'FALSE',
      'prevValue': ''
    },
    {
      'parameterName': 'remoteMacAddress',
      'newValue': 'a1-b1-c3-d4-e5-f6',
      'prevValue': ''
    },
    {
      'parameterName': 'yourName',
      'newValue': 'Vicky',
      'prevValue': ''
    }

    ],
    'class': 'EthernetLink'
  }
})
]
)
```

if the element is not present add the element else replace with new value.
Any help should be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. I 've written some comments in between to make it more readable:

```
# Get all current parameter names from dictionary 1.
currentDictParameterNames = [elem['parameterName'] for elem in dictionary_1['modifyParameterReq']['managedObject']['parameter']]

# Iterate through parameters from dictionary 2.
for index, dictData in enumerate(dictionary_2['modifyParameterReq']['managedObject']['parameter']):
    # If current key iterated from dictionary 2 exists in dictionary 1, update.
    if dictData['parameterName'] in currentDictParameterNames:
        # FInd the location of the parameter name in dictionary 1 and update.
        for i in range(len(dictionary_1['modifyParameterReq']['managedObject']['parameter'])):
            if dictionary_1['modifyParameterReq']['managedObject']['parameter'][i]['parameterName'] == dictData['parameterName']:
                dictionary_1['modifyParameterReq']['managedObject']['parameter'][i]['prevValue'] = dictionary_1['modifyParameterReq']['managedObject']['parameter'][i]['newValue']
                dictionary_1['modifyParameterReq']['managedObject']['parameter'][i]['newValue'] = dictData['newValue']
                break
    # Else create a new record.
    else:
        dictionary_1['modifyParameterReq']['managedObject']['parameter'].append(dictData)

print(dictionary_1)
```

The result should be:

```
{'modifyParameterReq': {'managedObject': {
    'distName': 'ethLink_1',
    'operation': 'create_mo',
    'parameter': [
         {'parameterName': 'houseName', 'newValue': 'Bhawan', 'prevValue': ''},
         {'parameterName': 'subscribe', 'newValue': 'FALSE', 'prevValue': 'TRUE'},
         {'parameterName': 'remoteMacAddress', 'newValue': 'a1-b1-c3-d4-e5-f6', 'prevValue': 'd6-68-05-5e-06-b9'},
         {'parameterName': 'yourName', 'newValue': 'Vicky', 'prevValue': ''}],
    'class': 'EthernetLink',
    }}}
```